# Using tkinter to watch for clipboard,what's wrong with my code?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, tkinter, clipboard

Some description about the code:

1. This is part of my program and I only put the related lines here
2. What I hope these code could do,is to watch for my clipboard.If I copy "**http:xxx**" to my clipboard,it shows a pop-up window.If the content of the clipboard doesn't change,the window won't show again
3. When running,it can pop up the window normally for one time,but won't do it again when I copy another string to clipboard starting with **'http:**'
4. I've tried some different interval values in the `after` method,same result.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox
import threading
import re

def watch_clipboard(tk,pipeout):  
    content = '' 
    last_content = ''
    while True:
        try:
            content = tk.clipboard_get()
        except TclError:
            pass
        result = re.match('http:',content)
        if content != last_content:
            if result:
                last_content = content
                message = 'show'.encode()    
                os.write(pipeout,message)


class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tk = Tk()
        self.tk.resizable(0, 0)
        self.tk.title('watch clipboard')
        pipein,pipeout = os.pipe()
        threading.Thread(target=watch_clipboard,daemon=True,args=(self.tk,pipeout)).start()
        self.tk.after(5000,lambda:self.clipboard_confirm(pipein))
        self.tk.mainloop()

    def clipboard_confirm(self,pipein):
        message = os.read(pipein,16)
        if message == b'show':
            self.tk.clipboard_clear()
            messagebox.askokcancel('', 'add this in?', default='ok')
            self.tk.after(5000,clipboard_confirm(pipein))   #add this


if __name__ == '__main__':
    gui = GUI()
```

EDIT:A. Rodas's code works.It seems that multithreading causes the problem.Deep reason remain unknown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think multithreading isn't the best approach for your situation and `after` may be enough. Instead of a busy waiting loop, you can call `tk.after` with a lower timeout. Then you just need to move the logic of `watch_clipboard` to your class, so you don't have to worry about the communication between the threads.

```
class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tk = Tk()
        self.tk.resizable(0, 0)
        self.tk.title('watch clipboard')
        self.last_content = ''
        self.tk.after(100, self.watch_clipboard)
        self.tk.mainloop()
    def watch_clipboard(self):
        try:
            content = self.tk.clipboard_get()
            if content != self.last_content and content.startswith('http:'):
                self.last_content = content
                self.tk.clipboard_clear()
                messagebox.askokcancel('', 'add this in?', default='ok')
        except TclError:
            pass
        self.tk.after(100, self.watch_clipboard)
```

Comment: No sense calling the function every 100ms. Given that this program is simply checking the clipboard, it's unlikely that any but the very fastest typers or mousers can copy two different strings to the clipboard in less than a second or two.

Comment: @BryanOakley I changed the frequency because 5 seconds might be a big delay between copying and showing the popup, but of course a greater value for the timeout can be more sensible.

Comment: The last time I wrote a program like this I think I settled on two or three seconds -- that uses just a tiny bit of CPU and in practice didn't miss any changes to the clipboard.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I misunderstood after and now I get it

Answer (score 1):

@laike9m
The error with your code is that os.pipe is used.
Os.read() is a blocking function that will receive os.read() blocking once `clipboard_confirm` is run. Causes the UI to get stuck.
This bug has nothing to do with `after` and multithreading.

Comment: Thanks. That might be the reason.

Comment: @laike9m If you are also interested in tkinter multi-threaded resolution monitoring clipboard issue, you can check out the results of my research. [my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54665708/tkinter-watch-clipboard-getmessage-no-return-value)

Answer (score 0):

There's a good chance the problem is related to using threads -- calling Tkinter functions from anywhere other than the main thread can cause problems.

Is there a reason you're using a thread rather than takingbadvantage of the built-in infinite loop (the event loop)? I would advise making use of `after` to check the keyboard every second or so.

Comment: Oh...I misunderstood the method after...I thought it is like settimeinterval in javascript,an in fact it's settimeout.Thank you for your answer,what a silly mistake

Comment: the reason I use thread is that I meant to watch the clipboard with no  timeinterval(turns out this is unnecessary)