# tkinter watch clipboard GetMessage no return value

Tags: python, winapi, tkinter, clipboard

i want to Monitoring Clipboard app for win10.
like: when we copy text 00-22-33-11-22 Mac Address from notepad.exe,tk's window get text and translate mac address to machine name.

---

but tkinter have no clipboard events.
so i call win32api
i search pywin32 document , found win32clipboard.SetClipboardViewer
but Creating a Clipboard Viewer Window is very complex
i search MSDN ， found  AddClipboardFormatListener is recommended 。this method is simpler to SetClipboardViewer. [MSDN Creating a Clipboard Format Listener](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/desktop/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard#monitoring-clipboard-contents)

i used it ,but  GetMessage always be blocked

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import threading as thrd
import win32gui
import win32clipboard
import win32api
import win32con
import ctypes
from ctypes.wintypes import MSG
from ctypes import byref


def selfevent(root):
    print("thrd start")
    hwnd = int(root.frame(), 16)
    done = ctypes.windll.user32.AddClipboardFormatListener(hwnd)
    print("done=", done)
    if done:
        wmsg = None
        print("begin GetMessage")
        wmsg = win32gui.GetMessage(None, 0, 0)
        # wmsg = MSG()
        # ctypes.windll.user32.GetMessageA(byref(wmsg), 0, 0, 0)
        print("GetMessage", wmsg.message(), win32api.GetLastError())
        if wmsg:
            print("msg=", wmsg)
            print(ctypes.windll.user32.RemoveClipboardFormatListener(hwnd))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("tktest")
    root.geometry("600x400")
    # root.bind("<<foo>>", vectrl)
    print("begin")
    txt = tk.Entry(root)
    txt.pack()
    bt2 = tk.Button(root, text="GetClipboardSequenceNumber", command=lambda: print("sn=", win32clipboard.GetClipboardSequenceNumber()))
    bt2.pack()
    t = thrd.Thread(target=selfevent, args=(root,))
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
    root.mainloop()
```

how to get WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE message?

---

my english is very poor.
run result:

```
begin
thrd start
done= 1
begin GetMessage
```

i copy anything , GetMessage are always blocked ,no return.
AddClipboardFormatListener is successful.
GetMessage(hwnd or None,0,0)
The results are the same.

Comment: Can we see _why_ it can't 'GetMessage'? If we don't know the actual error, then we can't really help you debug.

Comment: The call to GetMessage blocks because the thread does not receive any queued messages. This behaviour is as expected. I'd probably create a thread, create a message only window, and listen for the update messages in a message loop executing in that thread. A good grounding in Win32 programming is essential.

Comment: I thought that when I copied the text, the win system should send the message `WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE` to the root window.   
I want to get the message through `GetMessage`. However, no message is received by `GetMessage` in any case.  

How can I modify my code to get the message?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  Can you give me a simple example code to create an invisible window with pywin32 and get the `WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE'message?

Comment: No I cannot. I'm sure if you do some research you can find Python code to do all the different parts of this.

Comment: @Lordfirespeed， `GetMessage` runs differently than I expected. I expect to get the `WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE` message when the clipboard changes. But there is no message.   `AddClipboardFormatListener` is successful.

Comment: Relevant [using-tkinter-to-watch-for-clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590201/using-tkinter-to-watch-for-clipboard-whats-wrong-with-my-code)

Comment: @stovfl When the blocking function is used in the handler, it is a nightmare for the UI thread.My solution is more general.

Comment: @notback: Please make clear **which** is *"the blocking function"*

Comment: @stovfl Blocking functions like os.read, win32gui.GetMessage, queue.get, etc. Or CPU intensive operation: 999 ** 99 and so on. Or IO intensive operation: os.walk and so on.
`after` is only suitable for interface control. Just for the clipboard monitoring, `after` can be competent.
The post you gave me, the error is to use os.read() in the `after` function.

Comment: @notback: I agree, but the **accepted answer** doesn't use any of those operations? Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @stovfl  i'm Sorry, my English is very poor.I prefer a generic solution to similar problems(like watch folder, watch network etc..), not just clipboard monitoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have studied `GetMessage`, in the main thread, using `AddClipboardFormatListener` to register, using `GetMessage` is normal, but in the new thread, `GetMessage` always has no return value.
I have reviewed many of the forum posts, and basically mentioned that there are problems with multithreading of tk.
@stovfl mentioned the post, I read. I think that `after` is not a good idea.
`after` consumes main thread performance and affects UI display.
Use event to communicate on the page in vb.net. So I searched the tk documentation and found `event_generate`.
The test found that `event_generate` does not seem to be affected by multithreading.
Through the forum posts, I have completed some of the defects of `event_generate` and given my solution.

My code demonstrates monitoring the clipboard and launching a multi-threaded task with the button (traversing all the files in the path directory, finding the total number of files), the UI display is not affected by the task blocking.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import win32clipboard
import threading as thrd
import time
import os
from queue import Queue


def watchClip(top):
    lastid = None
    print("StartWatch")
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.01)
        nowid = win32clipboard.GetClipboardSequenceNumber()
        # print(nowid, lastid)
        if not lastid or (lastid != nowid):
            lastid = nowid
            top.event_generate("<<clipUpdateEvent>>", when="tail")


def workButton(top, path, outQueue):
    allcount = 0
    print("StartSearch")
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        allcount += len(files)
        top.clipboard_clear()
        top.clipboard_append(allcount)
    outQueue.put_nowait(allcount)
    # top.event_generate("<<searchFin>>", data={"result": allcount}, when="tail")
    top.event_generate("<<searchFin>>", data=f"result={allcount}", when="tail")


def bind_event_data(widget, sequence, func, add=None):
    def _substitute(*args):
        def evt():
            return None  # simplest object with __dict__
        try:
            evt.data = eval(args[0])
        except Exception:
            evt.data = args[0]
        evt.widget = widget
        return (evt,)

    funcid = widget._register(func, _substitute, needcleanup=1)
    cmd = '{0}if {{"[{1} %d]" == "break"}} break\n'.format('+' if add else '', funcid)
    widget.tk.call('bind', widget._w, sequence, cmd)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    top = tk.Tk()
    top.title("tktest")
    top.geometry("300x200")
    rsltQueue = Queue()
    # top.bind("<<foo>>", vectrl)
    print("begin")
    lbl = tk.Label(top, text="clipboard", width=30, height=3)
    lbl.pack()
    lblrslt = tk.Label(top, text="SearchResult", width=40, height=3)
    lblrslt.pack()
    prb = ttk.Progressbar(top, length=100, mode="indeterminate")
    prb.pack()
    txt = tk.Entry(top, width=20)
    txt.pack()
    prb.start(interval=10)
    t = thrd.Thread(target=watchClip, args=(top,), daemon=True)
    t.start()

    def searchPath():
        t = thrd.Thread(target=workButton, args=(top, "c:", rsltQueue), daemon=True)
        t.start()
    bt2 = tk.Button(top, text="SearchPath", command=searchPath)
    bt2.pack()
    clipText = ""

    def dealCUE(event):
        global clipText
        try:
            clipText = top.clipboard_get()
        except tk.TclError:
            pass
        lbl["text"] = clipText

    def dealSF(event):
        # lblrslt["text"] = f"allFileCount={rsltQueue.get()}"
        # lblrslt["text"] = event.data["result"]
        lblrslt["text"] = event.data
    top.bind("<<clipUpdateEvent>>", dealCUE)
    # top.bind("<<searchFin>>", dealSF)
    bind_event_data(top, "<<searchFin>>", dealSF)
    top.mainloop()
```

Python 3.7.2, os win10 1151, the test passed. (Continuous click on the button, open 12 worker threads, no problems found, UI thread is smooth)
If the code has an unexpected error, check tk*.dll in the python installation directory.
There is information that tk86t.dll supports multithreading, tk86.dll is not supported.
Thanks to @FabienAndre, @BryanOakley ,@stovfl and everyone in the discussion. You gave me the inspiration to solve this problem.
If you feel that this solution has some flaws, please let me know.