# Tkinter determine if clipboard has content

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a tkinter application, with a text widget in it.
The I tried to add a paste function:

```
def paste(self):
    self.text.insert('insert', self.text.clipboard_get())
```

But when the clipboard has no content, it pastes None.
I tried using a if condition to fix this:

```
if self.text.clipboard_get() == 'None':
    ...
```

It fixes some errors, but when the clipboard has 'None', it won't paste.
So how can I fix this?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think it is using the `None` object, not the string `'None'`. So try: `if self.text.clipboard_get() is None:`.

Comment: This can't be your real code. `self.text.insert(self.text.clipboard_get())` will throw an error. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks! I edited it.

Comment: Hard to believe you are the first person to ask this question and it was in 2021!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here `clipboard_get()` with an empty clipboard raise an error.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text()
text.clipboard_clear()
try:
    clip_text = text.clipboard_get()
    print(clip_text)
except tk.TclError:
    print('clipboard is empty')
```

Comment: Is it possible to 'hook' the clipboard so the application is notified when clipboard content is present?

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590201/using-tkinter-to-watch-for-clipboard-whats-wrong-with-my-code?rq=3